# Cant pass to another viewController,problems with navigation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cordova, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a working project, one of the screen is for example **ViewController 1** - tableView. i am trying to pass data and navigate to **ViewController 2** after selecting a row in ViewController 1. I added this code:

```
DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
dvController.selectedItem = selectedItem;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
[dvController release];
```

But its not passing to **ViewController 2**. I think the problem is with navigatorController.
Where should I add it? to xib file of ViewController 1? or to the mainAppDelegate - I dont want to touch it because its already working with its settings...

I declared UINavigationController *navigationController in my  appDelegate

What should I check?

After some changes to to code (thanks to @Vakul Saini)
appDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  self.View1 = [[startSearching alloc] initWithNibName:@"StartSearching" bundle:nil];
self.currentNC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.View1];

//this line start the startSearching at the begining and its passing to //secondViewController
    self.window.rootViewController = self.currentNC;
```

//  but with this line its start from the original start page but the transfer of views //doesn't wroks

```
 [self.window setRootViewController: self.viewController];
```

appDelegate.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) startSearching *View1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *currentNC;
```

startSearching.m

```
detailCon *detailCo =[[detailCon alloc] initWithNibName: @"detailView" bundle: [NSBundle mainBundle]];
[detailCon release];
UINavigation *currentNC1 = [[AppDelagate sharedInstance] currentNC];
[currentVC1 pushViewController:detailCo animated:YES];
```

Comment: just don't down vote any one's answer without understanding it and applying it or testing it. If you don't understand it properly juts ask it in comments :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you have a `UINavigationController` in your `Appdelegate` or not. You need to make your app `rootViewController` is `UINavigationController`
Add your `UINavigationController` in `appdelegate`

**Appdelegate.h file**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navCon;

@end
```

**Appdelegate.m file**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize viewController = _viewController;
@synthesize navCon = _navCon;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.navCon = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navCon;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Where `ViewController` is your firstView of app.

Comment: Thanks @VakulSaini but the tableView is on viewController 1, I need to implement didFinishLaunchingWithOptions there...

Comment: @vadim - But [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES]; line will not work you have not made your root view controller a navigationController.
And why down vote ?

Comment: Yes but the appDelegate is controlling other stuff too not only my Controller,I dont have there tableView...the viewController 1 opens from other viewController. This implementation I need to do in viewController 1 - there I have my tableView, the problem is how to set it all, so the ViewController would be the parent and viewController 2 the child

Comment: @vadim - Please try to understand this will not make any effect on your app ... and no need to viewController or tableView in appdelegate .... you just make your app with Navigation based other wise you can not navigate it with pushViewcontroller method ......

Comment: @vadim - Perhaps this would be easier if you showed how and where **view controller 1** is created since it's what needs to have a `UINavigationController` in order to push anything.

Comment: So what should I do?? How can I add it to appDelegate as you suggest if I don't have tableView there?

Comment: @vadim - First you are newB and when i gave you the proper answer you gave me one down vote while you dont know what do you want to do.... instead of argue try to understand what i'm saying .... just read above code .... then add your tableview in `ViewController` view then push next view from here .....

Comment: I did it... but I cant write - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in the appDelegate.What common to appDelegate and the tableView? Sorry but I don't see the logic here...

Comment: @vadim - This method is call every time when your app is launch.
So you need to set your navigation here....  and 1. why you cant write that method ??? 2. Why are you comparing a `UITableView` with `appdelegate` ? `Appdelegate` is file while `UITableview` is a controller .

Comment: @PhillipMills  its a phoneGap application so the viewController 1 is created when pressing button and its calling to method: AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*) [[UiApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; View1 *view1 = [[view1 alloc] initwithNibName:@"view1" bundle: nil];

Comment: @vadim - PhoneGap?  I wish you'd mentioned that to start with.  Bye, now.

Comment: @vadim - Where you mentioned it in your question ?
See your question... If you mention it in your question i never answer .... because i dont know about it.

Comment: @VakulSaini Well Its working if I am using that line of code:  self.window.rootViewController = self.navCon but its opening this viewController 1 at the start,I have already other viewController that should be opened in the start,Is any other changes should be made?

Comment: just replace `viewController` to what view you want to make your first view.

Comment: Yes I replaced it, but after replacing...it doesn't work, only when it's the first view at start...make sense?

Comment: Edit your question and show me the code where you have added your `navigationController` as a `rootViewController` ...

Comment: @vadim - first  [self.window setRootViewController: self.viewController]; line is wrong .... if you want to make this root view controller replace it with self.View1.... and another dont call your navigation like this UINavigation *currentNC1 = [[AppDelagate sharedInstance] currentNC]; just wirte [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailCo animated:YES];

Comment: Thank's for you help @VakulSaini!